# Extjs - prevent loading calendar event store

Tags: javascript, extjs, calendar

I'm using the Calendar component from Extjs 7.0, and at the moment it will load all the items from all calendars of the employees that are currently visible. Even if that calendar is hidden or not.

We are experiencing a bit of a slow performance when a lot of calendars are being shown and a lot of items have to be loaded. But since it also loading the items for calendars that are hidden it seems a bit of a waste. Below we have the store for calendars and the calendaritems. And I'm using the beforeload to prevent the calendaritems store from loading it's items that have their calendar hidden.

```html
config: {
        storeId : 'CalendarItems', 
        sorters: {
            property: 'title',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }      , 
        //Store doesn't have a model since Ext.calendar.store.Calendars has it's own model 
        proxy   : {
            type    : 'ajax',      
            url     : PdCConsts.APIUrl + '/Calendars.do',
            reader: {
                type        : 'json',
                rootProperty : 'items'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: false,
        eventStoreDefaults: {
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: PdCConsts.APIUrl + '/CalendarItems.do',
                reader: {
                    type        : 'json',
                    rootProperty : 'items'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                beforeload: function(store, operation){
                    if(store.calendar.get('hidden')){
                        return false;
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    },
```

And what I found out was that if I check in the beforeLoad event if the calendar is hidden or not, it won't show ANY of the items anymore... Doesn't matter if I return true or false, it just won't show the items anymore in the calendar.

Anyone have an idea why this happens?